# Explicit computation related to the fractional Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Suppose $$c_{n,s}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{(u(x+y+z)-u(x+y)-u(x+z)-u(x))^2}{|y|^{n+2s}|z|^{n+2s}} dydz = C$$
for some constants $c_{n,s}$, $C$, and $s \in (0,1)$.

Is it true that $$u = Cc_{n,s}(A - |x|^2)^s$$
holds for some $A>0$?

Comment: Of course not! Take any smooth $u_0$ with compact support. Then the integral is finite, and so $u = \lambda u_0$ for an appropriate $\lambda$ has the integral equal to $C$, but it is not of the desired form.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you! What if I add another assumption, for example that $(-\Delta)^s u = 1$?

Comment: Ah, I realise I did not read your question correctly. Let me think for a minute.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Ok, thanks! Please, let me know

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried to understand what the double integral really means, and I failed. If we integrate it over $x$, this seems to give the quadratic form corresponding to $(-\Delta)^{2s}$ (with $2s$ rather than $s$ in the exponent), which seems slightly odd. I'm afraid I cannot help much here, but if I may ask, out of curiosity: how did you come up with this expression? And why do you expect the claim to be true? I think I must be missing something obvious here.